# Python using Regex to split URL into multiple parts

Tags: python, regex

For the URL link below,

https://www.amazon.com/

https://amazon.com/

**How do I split them into three parts where:**

1st part: The scheme("https://")

2nd part: The domain(www.amazon or amazon)

3rd part: The top level domain ("com","edu"...)

**What I want it to return:**

('https://', 'www.amazon', 'com')

or

('https://', 'amazon', 'com')

**My approach:**

My idea is to use the pattern below, the first part (http[s]?://) is going to get the 1st part where the [s]? will also capture if there is no s such as "http://"

```
pattern = "((http[s]?://)((.+).))"
```

However, when I try to do the second part, I can't seem to get it to start searching after "https://" as it returns the following result with the code below:

Code that I ran:

```
re.search(pattern,'http://www.ycombinator.com/').groups()
```

The result I get:

```
('http://www.ycombinator.com/','http://','www.ycombinator.com/','www.ycombinator.com')
```

I am kinda stuck now, can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe all you want is `(https?://)(.+)\.(.+)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/BEZvxt/1))?

Comment: Red flag, trying to parse an url with a regex. How about you use the standard library to get the scheme and hostname ?
`>>> from urllib import parse
>>> parse.urlsplit('https://www.amazon.com/')
SplitResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.amazon.com', path='/', query='', fragment='')`. Also, you can't extract a TLD with a regex because TLDs can contain arbitrary dots (hello .co.uk), you can check https://publicsuffix.org/ and https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much for the help!  That is exactly what I want!  Also, regex 101 is really helpful!

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question with the answer in comment:

The answer that @Wiktor Stribiżew gave did the job perfectly!

```
(https?://)(.+)\.(.+)
```